# Why am I getting two different values for the environment variable PHPRC?

Tags: php, environment-variables

I've installed **PHP 7.2.12** using the latest version of **XAMPP**.

I ran the code `phpinfo();` and saw the output in the browser window.

In the output, under the heading **Apache Environment** I saw an **environment  variable** named `PHPRC` which has a value `\xampp\php`

Then I created a file named **demo.php** and wrote below code in it and run the same code file and see the output in my web browser.

```
<?php
   var_dump($_ENV['PHPRC']);
?>
```

I saw the below output in my browser window :

```
Notice: Undefined index: PHPRC in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo.php on line 2
NULL
```

Why so?

Why am I getting different and unexpected output when I tried to see the value of the **environment variable** `PHPRC` using superglobal array `$_ENV['PHPRC']`?

Comment: What does `var_dump( $_ENV );` produce?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus : `var_dump($_ENV);` produces `array(0) { }`. But why so? I mean why it's showing an empty array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the header "Apache Environment" tells you, this is set by the web server, not the OS, so won't be available within `$_ENV`. Instead try using the [`apache_getenv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-getenv.php) function.

```
echo apache_getenv("PHPRC");
```